# Does not display ampersand using $_GET in php

Tags: php, html, get, ampersand

I am trying to read a field in a table which contains this sentence "Sales & Logistics" using the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET['major1']))
{
    $major = $_GET['major1'];
}
else
{
    $major ="";
}
```

Unfortunately, $major will contains only "Sales " after this code while it should be "Sales & Logistics".

Note: '&' has not been converted into any shape, it has been saved as it is.

How can I read anything inside this table cell?

Thank You

Comment: I have no idea what the code you posted has to do with any table. However, it looks that you didn't convert the `&` properly when creating the query string. Functions like [`http_build_query()`](http://php.net/manual/function.http-build-query.php) are your friend

Comment: Because `&` is used to separate multiple parameters, like `/index.php?major1=SomeTxt&parameter2=otherText`. Not an issue I've faced before though, so not sure how to solve it.

Comment: you must urlencode() get parameters in urls

Comment: "Sales & Logistics" was saved in this table as it is without converting '&' into query string and cannot be change now. we need to extract the whole field with simplest way.

Comment: What "table" are you talking about? What does a table have to do with URLs and GET parameters?

Comment: We have a table called "resume" which already contains data. one of the columns called "major1". in some entries "major1" field will contains "Sales & Logistics". I cannot change any thing in this table which means that I cannot replace '&' with '%26'. What will be the best solution to read this whole sentence?

Comment: "Table" as in **MySQL table**?! You don't change anything about the data in that table. You just need to properly encode URLs in your HTML template, or wherever you're creating that URL.